# Using Intermediate Value Theorem and Rolle's Theorem to solve for roots.

Tags: calculus

I was having trouble with this question. You are supposed to use the Intermediate Value Theorem and Rolle's Theorem to prove that $x^{4}+4x-8$ has exactly two real roots. How would I do this? Thank you.

Comment: That polynomial has four distinct complex roots. Am I missing something?

Comment: I believe you mean to say that you wish to prove that $f(x) = x^{4}+4x - 8$ has exactly two *real* roots.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. It's been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^{4}+4x-8$. Note $f(1) = -3 < 0$, but $f(2) = 16 > 0$. Hence, $f(x)$ has a root in $(1,2)$. Further note that $f(-3) = 81 - 12 - 8 = 61 > 0$, so $f(x)$ has a root in $(-3, 1)$. (One can observe that $f(-2)=0$, alternatively.) Hence, $f(x)$ has at least two real roots.

Now differentiate $f(x)$ to find $f'(x) = 4x^{3}+4$. Factoring and setting $f'(x) = 0$, we see $f'(x) = 4(x^{3}+1) = 4(x+1)(x^{2}-x+1)$, which has exactly one real root, $x = -1$. Hence, by Rolle's theorem, we conclude...

Comment: Is the method behind plugging in the numbers at the beginning mainly a guess and check type of thing?

Comment: Mmmm, I wouldn't call it guess and check, but it isn't a deterministic/analytic process either. The key thing to notice in my mind is that the $x^{4}$ term will dominate $f(x)$ for large values of $x$, so $f(x)$ gets bigger and bigger as $x$ grows. By contrast, close to $0$, $x^{4}$ is very small, and the $-8$ constant term plays a much bigger factor. These are the kinds of heuristics you can apply to pick the right values, so that you can draw rigorous conclusions.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for your help

Comment: Though,mind you, I think the factoring might be wrong. Wouldn't it be 4(x^3 + 1)

Comment: Whoops! Good catch. The conclusion stands though. I'll edit it now.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. It makes sense now.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!